# sforce is not defined in UAT, but in sandbox yes

Tags: javascript, api, aura, opencti

I'm having this problem, and I've tried all the solutions that can be found in this world to resolve;

I'm working with the opencti APIs, in an aura component, in the sandbox the component runs fine (i developed it all on the sandbox), when passed to the test environment (UAT), when I try to open the component i get : "sforce is not defined".

Salesforce is complaining about this part :

```
 editPanel: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
    var params = evt.getParams();
    if (params.label) {
        sforce.opencti.setSoftphonePanelLabel({
            label: params.label
        });
    }
},
```

**sforce.opencti.setSoftphonePanelLabel**

I've imported openCTI, and I can see it from the browser, I tried to import connection.js and apex.js (as suggested many times) but I have the same error.

So I'm having this component fully working in sandbox refusing to start in the test environment, I don't know what to do.

Someone can help me?

Thank you in advance, Antonio.

The entire controller is:

```
    ({
    // Bring up the CTI login panel.
    init: function(cmp, event, helper) {
        console.log('init');
        // sforce.opencti.enableClickToDial(
        //     {
        //         callback: function() {
        //             cmp.getEvent('renderPanel').setParams({
        //                 type : 'c:phonePanel',
        //                 attributes: { presence : 'Unavailable'}
        //             }).fire();
        //         }
        //     });
    },

    // renderPanel event handler. Used to replace the current view with a given panel.
    renderPanel: function(cmp, event, helper) {
        var params = event.getParams();
        console.log('params', params);
        helper.renderPanel(cmp, params);
    },

    // editPanel event handler. Updates the softphone panel label.
    editPanel: function(cmp, event, helper) {
        var params = event.getParams();
        if (params.label) {
            sforce.opencti.setSoftphonePanelLabel({
                label: params.label
            });
        }
    },

    callAnswer: function(cmp, event, helper){
        console.log('callAnswer');
        var callback = event.getParams().callback;
        helper.callAnswer(cmp, callback);
    },

     // handler for the onlinePresenceChanged event. fired when the value of status dropdown is changing.
     onOnlinePresenceChanged: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        helper.updatePresence(cmp, event, helper);
   },


})
```

the solutions that I've tried:

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hSctAAE

All similar to this, the requireScript..
I also downloaded those libraries and uploaded them as static resource and tried to import them, but it doesn't work.

Yesterday, after 15 pm, the component was working WE DID NOTHING AT ALL.
Today, after a new changeset, is not working anymore.
I'm thinking that is a sforce problem, I don't understand what is happening, lol

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! I think it'll help if you include the entirety of your controller. It might also help if you were to go into a bit more detail (and/or provide links) about the solutions that you've found and tried so far. You can add this extra information to your question by making an [edit].

Comment: I edited the question, Thank you!!